# Find duplicates in Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts

I use [Google Contacts](http://www.google.com/contacts), but I find that I end up with quite a few duplicates (via multiple email addresses, sync issues etc). Is there any way that I can easily find a list of possible duplicates in my contacts?

I know once I've found them, I can merge them, but it's a bit annoying having to scroll through the list to spot them manually...

Comment: Could you please add a link to Google Contacts?

Comment: There is no link @mafutrct, it's integrated into other Google services, such as Gmail

Comment: Well, you can just go to http://www.google.com/contacts but I don't think you can use it standalone.

Comment: Of course you can use it standalone. I do it all the time.

Comment: Fair enough - link added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click on 'My Contacts' in the left vertical list of groups.

On the far right is the detail pane, and one of the buttons is: Find Duplicates.

Once you've got the list you can just check them all and merge them.

It's not bulletproof, but it's pretty good.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I thought the answer was going to be "tough, get on with doing it manually"... how have I missed this for all these years?! Shame I can only vote you up once! :)

Comment: LOL, I think they introduced it relatively recently; in the last year or so.  I know because the de-duping was driving my crazy before too.

Comment: It works for Google Apps as well. Just tested it! Thanks!

Comment: I find the lack of control in Google's Find Duplicates disturbing. It also had not found all my duplicate contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is a new service from Scrubly. The service scans and removes duplicate contacts from your Outlook, Gmail and Google Apps accounts. The nice thing about this service is that it gives you the option of viewing the contacts to be merged in advance and picking and choosing the info you want to merge so you have complete control over the merged data.  It also keeps a backup of your contacts.

Scrubly http://www.scrubly.com

Comment: Invite only at the moment. :(

Comment: Too bad that Scrubly.com costs $20 and doesn't tell you until you have gone through multiple steps. To be fair, there is a free version, but it doesn't apply to anyone who would be looking for such a tool because it is only for people with <250 contacts - in which case you should just manually dedup. I have 10x that and it simply would take too much time. But, as a student, not sure that I want to spend $20 on this.